# Oozie ssh action

Tags: hadoop, ssh, oozie

I am trying to run ssh action through Oozie work flow,

```
<action name="ssh-action">
    <ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
        <host>Server name.net<host>
        <command>echo</command>

    </ssh>
    <ok to="endjob"/>
    <error to="endjob"/>
</action>
```

I stored the work flow into hdfs, but when trying to connect the Server name.net from oozie server I am getting the following error message, could any one please help on this,

Error:
FNF: /var/tmp/oozie/oozie-dshm46789086433.dir/ssh/ssh.base.sh it looks it is related to oozie configuration, could any one please help on this to resolve this issue. My aim is to run a script on particular sever from Oozie server.

Comment: FNF indicates a 'File Not Found' error.  I'm not sure if that is referring to `/var/tmp/oozie/oozie-dshm46789086433.dir/ssh/ssh.base.sh` or `echo`.  Can you try running it with the full path to `/bin/echo`?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<action name="shell-action">
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                  <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                  <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <exec>example.sh</exec>
        </shell>
        <ok to="end" />
        <error to="kill" />
</action>
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to run an ssh action from oozie to an another server, the above sugesstion to ru a shell action, within the shell action is that possible to connect to an remote server ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this -

Step 1- create workflow.xml like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.3" name="sshAction">
  <start to="MySSHAction"/>
  <action name="MySSHAction">
    <ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
      <host>${sshHost}</host>
      <command>${shellScriptPath}</command>
      <capture-output/>
    </ssh>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
  </action>  
  <kill name="fail">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]. </message>
  </kill>
  <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Step 2 - configure job.properties

```
nameNode=hdfs://<namenode-machine>:8020
jobTracker=<resource-manager>:8050
queueName=default
shellScriptPath=/opt/example.sh
sshHost=oozie@localhost
```

Note - sshHost entry should be like this @ and make sure that there should be keyless access from oozie@oozie-host to @

Step 3- Write sample example.sh script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello Oozie"
```